# edit registry value data with whitespaces

Tags: regedit

I want to edit the Registry key's Data to be 'Do it' with dos-command, while 'Do it' contains a space, I tried many way but not work.

[registry_figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q48bU.jpg)

```
REG ADD HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\C1 /d Do it
```

Comment: Did you try quotes? `"Do it"`

Comment: Thanks jeb, "Do it" solved !

Answer (score 2):

Thanks **jeb** (he commented bellow the question) for sovling it

```
REG ADD HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\C1 /d "Do it"
```